# I want when I open the slide menu hamburger icon disappears

Tags: javascript

When I open the slide menu I see the hamburger icon visible.
my question is how I can make this hamburger icon invisible when the slide menu opens.
as you see above I have 2 id .one is side-bar and the other is open-slide.
which code I have to insert above in javascript or some condiitional code to make hamburger icon invisible when the slide menu opens.  can you write to me all the javascript code to achieve my goal.

my url is :http://webdesignleren.com

so you can see exactly what I mean.

```js
function openSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '250px';
}

function closeSlideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
}
```

```html
<div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
    <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
        <div id="open-slide">
            <svg width="30" height="30" style="margin-left:-10px;">
                <path d="M0 ,5 30 ,5" stroke="#003145" stroke-width="5" />
                <path d="M0 ,14 30 ,14" stroke="#003145" stroke-width="5" />
                <path d="M0 ,23 30 ,23" stroke="#003145" stroke-width="5" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">X </a>
    <div class="menu-bar">Menu</div>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="http://webdesignleren.com/">Home</a> </li>

        <li> <a href="http://webdesignleren.com/?page_id=7">Onderhoud</a> </li>

        <li> <a href="http://webdesignleren.com/?page_id=9">Banden</a> </li>

        <li> <a href="http://webdesignleren.com/?page_id=11">APK</a> </li>

        <li><a href="http://webdesignleren.com/?page_id=13">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a "**disabled**" class to your menu, after that, add a "**disabled**" addClass within the click function

Abaixo um exemplo

https://codepen.io/andsonlourenco/pen/XLgzjV

```
<input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
  <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
  </label>
```